# Windows Phone page navigation does not work

Tags: c#, .net, navigation, windows-phone-8.1

I'm new in creating apps for Windows Phone. I've got problem with redirecting to another page. I've created blank page with `HyperlinkButton`and in .cs file I wrote this:

```
private void but_elf_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Elfy));
}
```

In xaml:

```
<HyperlinkButton x:Name="but_elf" Content="Elfy"  
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="100,125,100,255" Grid.Row="1" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Height="70" />
```

When I launch app and click on the button - nothing happens. There are no errors, no messages. I've tried to put `NavigateUri` in button's property but after pressing button (in launched app) the message has shown: "You need to install an app for this task. Would you like to search for one in the Store?" After pressing "Yes" the app says: "Sorry, no apps found".

How to figure out this problem? I'm creating app for Windows Phone 8.1 in .NET Framework 4.5. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a reference for the 'Click'-event handler. Please change your XAML to this:

```
<HyperlinkButton x:Name="but_elf" Content="Elfy"  
HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="100,125,100,255" Grid.Row="1" 
VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Height="70" Click="but_elf_Click" />
```

Please see:

[C# Documentation for Click on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click.ASPx)

[C# Documentation for HyperlinkButton on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.hyperlinkbutton.aspx#events)